# MonoTouch.Dialog search filter not working properly for MessageElement cells

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, monotouch.dialog

I have the following code example to demonstrate a simple MonoTouch.Dialog table using `MessageElement` cells. The issue I am having is when I enable the automatic search feature in the `DialogViewController`. Whenever doing a search it always just displays a blank table.

If I replace the `MessageElement` cells with just `StingElements` cells the search works perfectly fine.

Does there need to be some additional code to search the `MessageElement` cells properly?

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace MessageElementSearch
{
    public class MessageTable : DialogViewController
    {
        public MessageTable(RootElement root) : base(root)
        {
            Section sec = new Section();

            root.Add(sec);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MessageElement me = new MessageElement();

                me.Sender = "Sender " + i.ToString();
                me.Subject = "Subject " + i.ToString();
                me.Body = "Body " + i.ToString();
                me.Date = DateTime.Now;

                sec.Add(me);
            }

            this.Style = UITableViewStyle.Plain;
            this.EnableSearch = true;
            this.SearchPlaceholder = "Filter Table...";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for MonoTouch.Dialog is available on github. From it you can see how `DialogViewController` [does it's search](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/DialogViewController.cs#L217) (it calls the `Matches` methods on the `Element`) and how you can tweak it to your liking.

In your case it happens that the `MessageElement` type does not override `Matches` so it fallbacks to the the default, from `Element` which use the `Caption` [do to it's searching](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L218).

The quick fix it to inherit your own element from `MessageElement`, e.g. `MyMessageElement`, and override `Matches` to work as you like.